# dotnet core default react template doesn't work

Tags: .net, reactjs, webpack, asp.net-core

I'm trying to play with dotnet core and default react template available via command `dotnet new react`.

Command that I use to run application in PowerShell:

```
dotnet new react
dotnet restore
npm install
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
dotnet run
```

The problem is after app is runned and browser is opened on localhost:5000 I see error:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-router/lib/withRouter.d.ts:3:99 
>       TS2314: Generic type 'PureComponent' requires 2 type argument(s).
>   ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:165:11 
>       TS2559: Type 'Component' has no properties in common with type 'ComponentLifecycle'.

[image]

Comment: I saw this question and answers doesn't help me. And I don't sure that author creates his project the same way as I wrote in description.

Comment: OK - will remove that flag. The conversation [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1066) might relate more closely to your issue (even though it involves the `react-redux` template).

Comment: template generator from https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/ works fine for me, but what the difference between template in command dotnet new and javascripservices?

Comment: The same happened to me right now restoring the project on another machine. The router issue I solved by setting explicit version for it: 
    "@types/react-router": "2.0.49", working on the react one now...

Comment: @GuillermoRuffino did you manage to find a fix for the react error?

Comment: @TamasPataky sorry not coming back before, this kind of issues seems to be related to the version of files @types/react-* as npm install runs it sometimes gets different versions (as newer version becomes available) and for some reason they are no longer very compatible with each other. If you have another older version working try using the npm ls command to see which version of every package you have in the working scenario and then use npm install with specific version to try to get it working.